# After rebuilding auto generated dlls isn't generating in another projects

Tags: c#, nuget, rebuild

I have two projects in my solution: Model and Client. In model I installed some packages from nuget (For example EF). I added Model in reference of client. After rebuilding solution in output of Model generates some dlls

[image: Output of Model project]

But in output of client there is only Model.dll

[image: Client project output]

Why another dlls isn't generating on Client project and how to generate dlls (Here EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll) in projects which are using Model project? (Without changing output of Model and installing nuget in another projects) Here is solution

[image: Solution]